Numpythonic ways of converting sparse to dense based on referenced index
I have this sparse vector val with this Pythonic way:
idx = [2, 5, 6]
val = [69, 12, 15]

_ = np.zeros(idx[-1]+1)

for i in idx:
  _[i] = val[idx.index(i)]

print(_)
dbg(_)

Here is the output:
[ 0. 0. 69.  0. 0. 12. .15]
(6,)
float64

How do I achieve my goal where it's not using for loops, instead using a Numpythonic way?

Scipy has sparse arrays/matrices. They can be converted to/from Numpy dense ones. Using them should be faster/simpler/reliable/more-pythonic than using loops in most cases. It is mainly designed for 2D cases (though it seems to support >2D arrays). Maybe 1D COO arrays work.

Set all val at once _[idx] = val

@hpaulj Thanks, I didn't expect the answer is basic like that.

idx = [2, 5, 6]
val = [69, 12, 15]

_ = np.zeros(idx[-1]+1)

numpy lets you set multiple values at once
_[idx] = val


Method 1(most efficient for Huge datasets) :
import torch
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

idx = [2, 5, 6]
val = [69, 12, 15]

sparse_matrix = csr_matrix( (val, (np.zeros(len(idx)),idx)),shape= (1, idx[-1] +1))
print(sparse_matrix)
'''
  (0, 2)    69
  (0, 5)    12
  (0, 6)    15
'''

res = sparse_matrix.toarray().flatten()
print(res)#[ 0  0 69  0  0 12 15]

Method 2(Less efficient) :
import torch
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

idx = [2, 5, 6]
val = [69, 12, 15]

# Create a zero-filled array with the appropriate length
result = np.zeros(idx[-1] + 1, dtype=np.float64)

# Use NumPy's advanced indexing to set values at specified indices
result[idx] = val

print(result)
'''
Output: [ 0.  0. 69.  0.  0. 12. 15.]
'''

